# Routing traffic to an ELB load balancer giving 404 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-status-code-404, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have seen quite a few posts talking almost about the same, but none of those covered my case.

I have 2 accounts, A and B, in which:

- In **account A** I have a hosted zone with the domain, `domainA.com` and a load balancer.
- In **account B** I have another hosted zone, which is a subdomain, `staging.domainA.com` and another load balancer.

I would like to redirect from one record in `domainA.com` hosted zone, `product.domainA.com` to the ELB load balancer in account B, `product.staging.domainA.com`.

I have thoroughly followed the steps documented in [Routing traffic to an ELB load balancer](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html)
. An even, they appear to cover my case, because the doc refers at some point in steps 1 and 6 to have a hosted zone and ELB load balancer in different accounts.

Unfortunately, it's not working. I'm getting a 404 error not found. When using `dig` command the output is exactly the same:

```
tomas@DESKTOP-EMM3Q9L:~$ dig product.domainA.com
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.13-Ubuntu <<>> product.domainA.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55731
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;product.domainA.com.              IN      A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
product.domainA.com.       60      IN      A       X.X.X.X
;; Query time: 41 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 08 16:30:21 STD 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 50
====================================================================================================================================
tomas@DESKTOP-EMM3Q9L:~$ dig product.staging.domainA.com
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.13-Ubuntu <<>> product.staging.domainA.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41318
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;product.staging.domainA.com.      IN      A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
product.staging.domainA.com. 41    IN      A       X.X.X.X
;; Query time: 15 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 08 16:30:58 STD 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58
```

(Actual domain names have been changed as well as IP, which in this case, `X.X.X.X` represents the SAME IP address in both `dig`.

Do you know what may be going on? Let me know if you need further details. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your web server is returning a `404` response because it can't match the HTTP request to anything. I'm not aware of any scenario where a load balancer would return a `404`.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you. Both DNS names of the ELBs gives `404` error when trying to access through Web, but the one in `product.staging.domainA.com` goes fine. Both ELBs points to a EKS cluster.

Comment: @MarkB It could be due to an ALB listener rule: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75518004/3263374 only accepting requests from specific hosts and domains

Answer (score 0):

This could very much be because of a listener rule in your ALB, that only accepts requests from a particular host / domain name.

Check them, and see whether the 404 error could be due to that. In my case at least, it was about that.

For more see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html